# In Rails, can I set a has_many relation on a model from another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many, belongs-to

Is there any way I can set both halves of a belongs_to/has_many relation in just one of the models? So I want do something like:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a
  A.has_many :b
end
```

Obviously this doesn't work (or I would have used it) but I hope it explains what I mean...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this? It's a rather odd request.

Comment: What is the problem with doing it separately?

Comment: It comes from a system I'm writing where I wanted it to be as easy as possible to extend functionality by adding a new model with very little functionality. I've pushed most of it to a superclass, achieves a lot of this (including the belongs_to part) but all of these added models also need a has_many on a single other one.

Comment: It's not *important* but I was interested in seeing how far I could abstract everything out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd want to, but assuming you have a great reason...

`has_many` is just a class method defined in ActiveRecord::Base so calling `A.has_many :b` should work.

You might have issues however in development with loading order. If you load up the example you gave and called `a = A.new`, the class B has never been loaded, so `a` has no idea that `A` has many `B`. In production, where the entire class list is loaded on start, this won't be  a problem. In development you can get around it by using a `require` statement, however, you are then coupling the two files together pretty strongly.

I haven't tried it, but in theory, that's the only thing I can think of that is preventing your setup above from working.

Comment: Aha. That makes sense. I bumped into a similar problem when I tried using Class.inherited. It worked perfectly, but _only_ if the other models had already been seen.  Thanks :)